# Should I cache PIP_CACHE_DIR and POETRY_CACHE_DIR or venv if distributed cache is enabled?

Tags: python, gitlab-ci

I want to cache those two directories (`PIP_CACHE_DIR` and `POETRY_CACHE_DIR`) to make the pipeline faster and cheaper.

Faster because I need to download all the dependencies for every job every time it runs (hundreds of times a day) and also I pay for the bandwidth to the cloud provider.
I wanted to use the local cache but distributed cache is enabled (to GCP cloud storage) because the GitLab CI runners are pods on Kubernetes and can change their node.

Is there any added value from still catching those libraries? Or it doesn't matter because I still need to download and upload it which can even take more time?

Even worse is that for every job this cache will be downloaded but won't all of it be used every time.

I thought of just caching the venv directory of every repository but I think the same problems still exist.